# What mean "peley" and "nava mina"?

Tags: words, hebrew, talmud-gemara, aramaic

At a gemara Shiur, I often heard the expression "it is peley" and the word "navamina". I do not know what these words mean. Navamina is not in the Melamed Dictionnary... Can you please tell me the meaning of these words / expressions ?

Comment: far22, are you the same person as [JOJO](/u/8577) or [jojo](/u/8579)? You seem to be asking a very similar style of question. If so, you might be interested in [asking for your accounts to be merged](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That way, you can keep track of all of your activity here in one place.

Comment: Yes I now use this account only (far22). It is more practical I think. It is a real account whereas Jojo was just a guest account.

Comment: Well, it would be tidier if you could get the two previous accounts merged into this one, so that all your stuff is together.

Comment: I just asked for these accounts to be merged.

Comment: How are these questions objectively answerable? "What word did my Rabbi say that sounds like _flumpdigy_?" "I don't know; go ask him!" Motion to close this and all the others like it as POB.

Comment: It might be useful for you to check out the [Mi Yodeya glossary](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/581/mi-yodeya-glossary). It has lots of definitions of commonly used words.

Comment: far22, hi man, give some contact on you, i can answer all your questions about this expressions zeev.breiner at gmail.com contact me!

Comment: @DoubleAA : Not that easy to do! This is not the kind of shiur in which you can ask question! And please be more polite. I don't understand why you're so rude.

Comment: I back @DoubleAA's motion to close. I would also close all questions that ask about even understandable word definitions w/o indicating additional reason for knowing just the definition - consistent w/ M.Y. policy of asking questions about Hebrew (which should include Aramaic) language / history, etc.

Comment: @danf I need it to understand the gemara. Is it a good reason ?

Comment: @DanF, far22's stated reason of wanting to understand a gemara class is definitely sufficient to make this on-topic. The problem here, though, is that it's impossible for us to objectively evaluate any guesses as to which phrases this question refers to, since they're transcribed imperfectly and ambiguously, we don't have the original class to compare to, and there's insufficient context provided to make it clear. See the extended chat conversation starting [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19149123#19149123).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "peley", but I imagine that the phrase you are hearing as "navamina" is actually "hava amina," which means "what one would have thought". For example, the Gemara might state a fact that seems obvious, and the person leading the shiur might ask, "What's the hava amina?"  In other words, why did the gemara have to say that? What else would I have thought?

It doesn't have to be used in that negative context, though. You could also say, "If the mishna hadn't said that, the hava amina would have been X.  Now that we know Y, we know X is not true and in fact, Z is true."

EDIT:

It occurred to me that instead of "hava amina" you might have actually been mishearing the expression "nafka mina", which means practical difference. For example, two amoraim could be arguing about the reason for some halacha and the gemara could ask "Mai nafka mina?" Meaning, what practical difference in the practice of the halacha would we observe depending on which amorah is correct? The gemara then goes on to answer how the difference in reason for the din could actually affect what the halacha is in some particular scenario.

Comment: Could also be Nafka Minah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, nafka minah also occurred to me just before reading your comment

Comment: It is actually hava amina. But what mean the two words in hava amina and nafka mina?

Comment: those are two different words, amina - i said, mina - from it.

Comment: @far22 "hava" is a form of the verb "to be". "amina" is connected to the word for believing something to be true. "Nafka" means to go out and "mina" means "from it". Both phrases are expressions which do not really translate well literally.

Comment: Or maybe 'hahu mina'

Answer (score 5):

The word "peley" is probably פלא, which means it is a "wonder" or something amazing or incredible.  It often refers to something being very surprising in its novelty.

I assume Daniel is correct about "navamina"